# gRPC, ProtoCol BUffers and Flutter on OSx

Tags: dart, flutter, protocol-buffers, osx-yosemite, grpc

I'd like to use gRPC / ProtoBuffers between a Flutter/Dart app developed on OSx and a GoLang server. My thought is to replace a REST connection.  My problem is that I cannot install Protobuf on OSx for DART.... or at least, I can't seem to figure it out.
This URL, towards the end, says that Protobuf for DART is only supported for Ubuntu.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/protobuf/+/HEAD/README.md

QUESTIONS

1. Is this correct that Protobuf on OSx for Dart Flutter is not working yet?
2. Any tips or tricks to make it work?  and I missing something here?

Comment: I'm not sure if you got it working. But I recently wrote a blog post for this https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-grpc-810f87612c6d , and yes dart. flutter, GRPC, everything related to these work on Mac OS.

Comment: @ishaan your guide does not work anymore, btw... I tried it a while back. Maybe you could post an update?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should install protobuf by homebrew.
`brew install protobuf`
If you don't have `brew` command, see how to install package manager HomeBrew for MacOsX.

Second, you should install Dart, see here https://www.dartlang.org/tools/sdk#install

Third, install plugin dart-protoc-plugin
https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-protoc-plugin#how-to-build-and-use

Fourth, see this guide how to generate .dart classes
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/darttutorial

Fifth, follow this guide for dart-grpc
https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/dart.html

Comment: I've done all this for golang on windows and OSx.  My question was specific to DART/FLUTTER on OSx.  The first line of Procedure 3 above is... " Note: currently the workflow is POSIX-oriented."   which is not OSx.  Which gets back to my original question, will this work for Flutter/DART on OSx?  otherwise all of these comments are right out of the Howtos.

Comment: I've already done ProtoBuff+Flutter on MacOSx implemented to AndroidApp, and didnt see any problem there. You write your own smth.proto file, generate dart class, import needed packages, and use generated classes. Where you have problem, your cannot generate dart class?

Comment: So you have this working on OSx for Dart?   You have it running for Android, but have not made it work on iOS.     OK...I think my issue is getting the ProtoBuff complier for dart to work on OSx.  The Docs say that dart compiler only works for Ubuntu, which is why I posted the question.  I wanted to confirm that.. and see if there was a work around.